# Solr reindex is stopping prematurely when running Collective Solr for Plone

Tags: solr, lucene, plone

My team is working on a search application for our websites. We are using Collective Solr in Plone to index our intranet and documentation sites. We recently set up shared blob storage on our test instance of the intranet site because Solr was not indexing our PDF files. This appears to be working, however, each time I run the reindexing script (@@solr-maintenance/reindex) it stops after about an hour and a half. I know that it is not indexing our entire site as there are numerous pages, files, etc. missing when I run a query in the Solr dashboard.

The warning below is the last thing I see in the Solr log before the script stops. I am very new to Solr so I'm not sure what it indicates. When I run the same script on our documentation site, it completes without error.

```
2017-04-14 18:05:37.259 WARN  (qtp1989972246-970) [   ] o.a.s.h.a.LukeRequestHandler Error getting file length for [segments_284]
```

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/solr/data/uvahealthPlone/data/index/segments_284

I'm hoping someone out there might have more experience with Collective Solr for Plone and could recommend some good resources for debugging this issue. I've done a lot of searching lately but haven't found much useful info.

Comment: I posted a link to your question on our forum, where usually you'll get more eyeballs https://community.plone.org/t/stack-overflow-solr-reindex-is-stopping-prematurely-when-running-collective-solr-for-plone/4008

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug fixed some time ago with https://github.com/collective/collective.solr/pull/122